# I need advice with Microsoft Access Configuration with linked table

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm working on a database project using microsoft access and I have run into a problem.

I want the users to each have their own GUI so multiple people can be in or make data changes to the database at the same time so what I did was I developed the database with the gui...

I then created a much improved GUI by creating a separate msaccess file with a much improved GUI. In this file, Under the "External Data" tab in Access, there was an option to link tables to an access database.I chose this and linked the tables to the original ms access database i created first.

But now I just learned that you can split a database into two files under the "Database Tools" tab...

I've alerady created the improved gui with the separate Msaccess file i created. I just linked them to the main database file.

**My question** Will this give me the same outcome if I do it the way i've already done it, or do I need to actually  use the original database file split it into two files. After reading the Microsoft support article, it looks like I did it backwards... I created the database first and then created the guis separately and linked to the database when I should have did everything in the database then split it using using the Split database tool...

Will the outcome be the same or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same outcome. The Access Splitter on the Ribbon is simply an easy button click wizard to do automatically what can be done manually. Like the other wizards (query design, form design, report design), the splitter is mainly for non-experts who may not understand the split database architecture.

Normally, it is recommended to split databases, essentially starting with two separate BE and FE files, from the beginning as part of your database design. This way you avoid any caching, bloating, memory usage that comes with combining data (tables) with application (queries, forms, reports, macros, modules). Of course you can always compact! Another particular reason to split early on is that you may need multiple Access backends but the splitter tool moves all tables into only one Access backend file.